# EEA Brexit wife of British national

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I am the wife and mother of British passport holding husband and son. I am Indonesian. We live in Spain, I have residency in Spain.
With Article 10 I could enter UK with husband for free, no visa.

Now Brexit has removed that. EEA family permit is also going.

Can anyone tell me why I need to buy a visa for every trip just like any random solo traveller from a non EU place? I am a direct family member with proven legal marriage and legal parents in law in UK. My husband and son could travel at the drop of a hat and I would not be able to go with them. A visa is not an easy or cheap process and we also do not live near Madrid.

Please help us.

Should we buy a 1000 pounds ten year visa or is there a free option like there should be?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately for you, the conditions under which you can enter the UK are now the same as they would be if you resided with your British citizen family anywhere else in the world.  In other words, you need a standard visitor visa.

I would not advise applying for a ten-year visa unless you can demonstrate a long history of short visits to the UK.  Even then I would suggest that you consult a good UK immigration lawyer before making the application.  If the home office decides that you deserve only a six-month visa, they will grant the six-month visa without refunding the difference in the application fee.

Comment: so crazy. how can they not recognise that i need to be able to go into the UK often and I am not taking up job or nhs space

Comment: So the EEA is useless now?

Comment: @Yona McCrum How often is ‘often’, and why do you ‘need’ to visit the UK frequently? If you can demonstrate a compelling reason for your visits your chance of a 2, 5, or 10 year visitor visa is likely higher.

Comment: @YonaMcCrum the EEA isn't useless, but the UK is no longer a member of the EEA.

Comment: hi often would be 2 or 3 times per year. the reason would be to visit the baby's grandparents in Northern Ireland, my in laws. My husband will want to spend a few months at home each year, because of me, he can't go.